# Getting data from input text to variable

Tags: jquery, input

Question: Why I can't get the value of the input text `#userGuess` into the variable `userInput`?

Here is the HTML

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style="text-align:center">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Guessing Game</legend>
                <label>Input a number in your mind</label>
                <input type="text" id="userGuess" auto-complete="off">
                <span class="help-block" style="display:block">
                    <p class="help-block" id="resultWaiting" style="display:block">Results!</p>
                    <p class="help-block" id="resultWarmer" style="display:none; color:#E61010">Warmer!</p>
                    <p class="help-block" id="resultColder" style="display:none; color:#104CE6">Brr! Colder</p>
                    <p class="help-block" id="resultCorrect" style="display:none; color:#E61010">YES! YOU GOT IT</p>    
                </span>
                <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Show Result</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript code

```
    $("#submitButton").click(submit);
function submit() {
    var userInput = $('#userGuess').val();
    if (userInput == pcRandom) {
        $("#resultWaiting").css("display","none");
        $("#resultCorrect").css("display","block");
    } else{
        compare(userInput, pcRandom);
    }
}
```

While debugging on Chrome Dev Tools, it just said the userInput variables is undefined.

I use Bootstrap for css framework and jQuery

Comment: should, best practice, not must. JavaScript organizes this internally: http://jsfiddle.net/uJDnd/

Comment: Don't see any problem with code. Its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/CUDJR/

Comment: Note: @TheVillageIdiot has taken out the <form> tag.

Comment: @ManavKataria even with that it will not make any difference. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/CUDJR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me after I added a `event.preventDefault()` to the jQuery. However, this is assuming that `compare` compares the two guesses and changes the CSS accordingly, and that `pcRandom` picks a random number:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    submit();
});

function submit() {
    var userInput = $('#userGuess').val();
    var pcRandom = 5;
    console.log(userInput);
    if (userInput == pcRandom) {
        $("#resultWaiting").css("display","none");
        $("#resultCorrect").css("display","block");
    } else{
        compare(userInput, pcRandom);
    }
 }
```

EDIT:

Here's a fully functioning JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9VYvg/